# Running a query in grails with two 'like' conditions with an OR in between

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm

I am trying to run a grails query which is as follows

`select * from table where col1 like 'abc%' or col2 like 'abc%'`

When I run `DomainClass.executeQuery` it fails with the error table_name not mapped. I dont know how to write it in createCriteria. Can you please provide some guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use criteria:

```
def c = Table.createCriteria()
def results = c.list {
    or {
        like("col1", "abc%")
        like("col2", "abc%")
    }
}
```

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html

Comment: Thanks!!! This solution works! How do I learn what parameters I can pass to the "list" api? For instance, in this case we seem to be passing a closure? Is there a way for me to find out how to construct an OR closure?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the executeQuery:

```
DomainClass.executeQuery("from table t where t.col1 like 'abc%' or t.col2 like 'abc%'")
```

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeQuery.html